# Map through Array object stored in state

Tags: reactjs, api

Im trying to access data from an API and render the results. Im storing each object in a separate state and im trying to map through each state, however this throws the following [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ds84M.png).

My code is:

```
    state = {
        events: [],
        items: [],
        isLoading: true
    }

    // fetchData = () => {
    componentDidMount() {
        const url = 'http://www.mocky.io/v2/5c8673f0340000981789c0da'
        axios.get(url).then(response => {
            this.setState({ items: response.data, isLoading: false, events: response.data[0] })
            console.log(this.state.events)
        })
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <div>
                    <h1>26/2</h1>
                    <ul>
                        { this.state.events.map(event => (<li>{event.activity}</li>)) }
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h1>27/2</h1>
                    <ul>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

API structure:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "activity": "lunch",
    "startDate": "2019-02-26 12:00",
    "endDate": "2019-02-26 13:00",
    "location": "Lagerhuset"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "activity": "meeting",
    "startDate": "2019-02-26 22:00",
    "endDate": "2019-02-27 07:00",
    "location": "online"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "activity": "meeting",
    "startDate": "2019-02-26 10:00",
    "endDate": "2019-02-26 12:00",
    "location": "Lagerhuset"
  }
]
```

Now im wondering if what I'm trying to achieve even is possible? And if so, what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`items` contain the array of items. `events` just contain the first item which is an object. Hence the map fails.

Either use :

```
{this.state.items.map(event => (
  <li>{event.activity}</li>
))}
```

or this :

```
<li>{this.state.events.activity}</li>
```

Comment: The above code gives me this error:
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): response.json is not a function